# How to cycle through functions that service input elements in Java

Tags: java, selenium

There is a registration form which has a number of mandatory fields. The following test will be performed:

- In each iteration, enter into each of these fields a value or execute the appropriate action (like click or select)
- EXCEPT for one - so in every iteration should be left out a different field

This simulates a user that wants to register but forgot to enter a value. An appropriate error should appear.

In the page object I have predefined methods for each of these input elements (`setFirstName()`, `setLastName()`, `clickSomething()` etc.) - these are used by other test cases. Obviously I could just copy and paste the methods ten times over and leave one out every time but that is far from elegant. Another obvious solution would be to create a separate object for ever input element on the page and put the objects into a list; but that is rather extensive as well.

Is there an easy way to cycle through a select group of methods belonging to an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the situation ended up to be even more complex, so it was necessary to create an object that handles the input field and its error field at the same time, along with some more convenience functions.

> ```
>   protected class InputElement{
>     private By input;
>     private WebElement inputElement = null;
>     private By errorField;
>     private WebElement errorElement = null;
>     private String value;
> ```

```
    protected By getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    protected String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    protected WebElement getInputElement() {
        return inputElement;
    }

    protected WebElement getErrorElement() {
        return errorElement;
    }

    protected void setValue(String value){
        this.value = value;
        if(inputElement == null){
            inputElement = driver.findElement(input);
        }

        inputElement.clear();
        inputElement.sendKeys(value);
    }

    protected void clear(){
        if(inputElement == null){
            inputElement = driver.findElement(input);
        }

        inputElement.clear();
    }

    protected void setValue(){
        setValue(this.value);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is currently an error message.
     * 
     * @param input
     * @return true if an error exists for this element. 
     */
    public boolean hasError(){
        errorElement = elementExistsInContext(inputElement, errorField);
        if(errorElement == null){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected InputElement(By input, By errorField){
        this.input = input;
        this.errorField = errorField;
    }

    protected InputElement(By input, By errorField, String value){
        this.input = input;
        this.errorField = errorField;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```